# Does Brownian motion immediately visit both sides of a Jordan curve?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $C$ be a Jordan curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  By the Jordan curve theorem, $\mathbb{R}^2 \smallsetminus C$ is uniquely partitioned into two connected regions $A$ and $B$ (the interior and exterior).

**Question 1:** Let $x_0$ be an arbitrary point in $A$.  Let $X$ be a planar Brownian motion starting at $x_0$.  Let 
$$\tau_C = \inf \{t: X(t) \in C \},\qquad\tau_B = \inf \{t: X(t) \in B \}.$$
Does $\tau_C = \tau_B$ a.s.?

**Question 2:** Let $y_0$ be an arbitrary point on $C$.  Let $Y$ be a planar Brownian motion starting at $y_0$.  Let 
$$\tau_A = \inf \{t: Y(t) \in A \},\qquad\tau_B = \inf \{t: Y(t) \in B \}.$$
Does $\tau_A = \tau_B = 0$ a.s.?

**Observations:**

- A positive answer to question 2 gives a positive answer to question 1.  (Let $y_0 = X(\tau_C)$.)
- The answers to both questions 1 and 2 are clearly true for "nice curves", for example smooth curves or curves with some kind of cone condition on each side.  However, possibly some messy curves (e.g. ones with positive 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure) would present a problem.
- If the answer to either question is yes, it would be interesting to know the answer in higher dimensions as well (replacing Jordan curves with their higher dimensional analogues).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to explain a little more fully why the questions are affirmative for "nice" curves?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: So here's an explanation in case where the curve is a straight line. Without loss of generality, you can assume the curve is $x=0$. Now it's known that 2-dimensional Brownian motion is the same as independent Brownian motions in each of the coordinates. Also it's known that 1-dimensional Brownian motion started from 0 almost surely takes positive and negative values in any time interval $[0,\epsilon]$.

Comment: Thanks, @AnthonyQuas, although I think that much was already clear to me. It seems, however, that what I really need to do is to study up on the 1-dimensional Brownian motion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As to question 2: Planar Brownian motion started at $y_0$ will almost surely loop around $y_0$, i.e., disconnect $y_0$ from $\infty$ immediately, so it has to hit $A$ and $B$ immediately, too, and $\tau_A = \tau_B = 0$ a.s., no matter what kind of Jordan curve $C$ is. This should also imply that the answer to the first question is yes, by the strong Markov property.

In higher dimensions there are easy counterexamples to question 2. E.g., if $C$ is a topological sphere, smooth except for one point where it is locally the "Lebesgue thorn", i.e., with one irregular boundary point $y_0$, then one of the stopping times is almost surely positive. I am not sure about question 1 in higher dimension.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to provide a reference to the two mentioned results?

Comment: I'm having technical troubles upvoting your answer (since this isn't a registered account and it won't let me register it).  But it is worth upvoting.

Comment: I don't have standard references handy, but if nobody else comes up with it, I will try to dig out some.

Comment: The Lebesgue thorn is a standard example of an irregular point in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and it is discussed in all standard references. For a web source see http://wiki.math.toronto.edu/TorontoMathWiki/index.php/Brownian_Motion_and_Harmonic_functions. I don't really have a reference for the looping, but it is easy to prove. First you show that a Brownian motion in the unit disk started at a point $|z|=r \in (0,1)$ has a positive probability of looping $0$ before hitting the boundary, and then you use scale invariance and Markov property.